# Redirect with Variables in Laravel | Payment Gateway

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I see a lot of similar questions are being asked on stack overflow but none seem to work for me. Hence asking here.

The case is simple. I am trying to integrate with a payment gateway - which is asking me to submit a form with a set of data to it's url.

URL: 
`https://test.examplepg.com/_payment`

Form\Parameters:

```
<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" name="payuForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php csrf_token() ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="<?php echo $MERCHANT_KEY ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="<?php echo $hash ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="txnid" value="<?php echo $txnid ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $amount ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="<?php echo $firstname ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo  $email ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone  ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="productinfo" value="<?php echo "Product 1, 2"?>" size="64" />
    <input type="hidden" name="surl" value="<?php echo $successUrl?>" size="64" />
    <input type="hidden" name="furl" value="<?php echo $failureUrl?>" size="64" />
    <input type="hidden" name="bankcode" value="<?php echo $bankcode; ?>" />
    ....

    <?php if($hash) { ?>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <?php } ?>
</form>
```

Instead of creating a form/view and writing javascript to submit the form, I would like to do a **laravel redirect with post data** (or something similar). Is it possible?

Curl wouldn't work as the user needs to be on their url for verification.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you're being too literal. "submit a form" doesn't mean you have to build actual html and then somehow click the submit button. It just means you send over an http request with what a form BECOMES when the submit button is clicked.

Comment: have a look Guzzle....

Comment: @SimonDavies I see Guzzle has synchronous requests, like $client->post();. Would it redirect to the new url? 
https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/docs/quickstart.rst

Comment: @MarcB Couldn't come up with better wording. :)

Comment: @SimonDavies Also is there a laravel package?

Comment: i knwo what you mean as i've built a store with a separate payment back end, and to then do the payment section it then went to a separate page that then automated the post to the payment client, using a similar method above, but your after the same thing but for Laravel to forward the post data instead, yes? Guzzel is a package that you can download into Laravel and use.

Comment: Might be a good idea if not already to have a look at the payment client your suing to see if they have any packages etc, or proceeses that enable you to do so using a third party in btween like Guzzle etc, who's the payment client end?